# Get all posts from users that are not blocked in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel 5.8 application where one user can block another user.

User model:

```
public function blockedUsers()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'blocked_user', 'user_id', 'blocked_id');
}
```

Now every user can post articles. How to get all articles that are posted by non blocked users in users feed.

If I do:

```
$posts = Post::all();
```

Obviously I will get all posts, so how to make a where conditin and say all posts that are created by a user which is not blocked by `Auth::user()`?

```
$user = Auth::user();
$posts = Post::where(function($q) use ($user){
      // Can't figure out this part
})->get();
```

Comment: How about `Post::doesntHave('blockedUsers')->get();`? But I'm wondering why blockerUsers() relation is on User model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get your blocked user ids and use it later in the query to check if the creator of the post is one of the blocked ids using `whereNotIn()`

```
$user = Auth::user();

// Get list of blocked user ids 
$blockedIds = $user->blockedUsers->pluck('id')->toArray();

// NOTE: I am assuming the field that hold the post creator id is user_id
// Get all post where the creator id is not in the blocked ids array
$posts = Post::whereNotIn('user_id',$blockedIds)->get();
```

Alternatively you can also write it like this

```
$user = Auth::user();
$posts = Post::where(function($q) use ($user){
      $q->whereNotIn('user_id', $user->blockedUsers->pluck('id'))
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_id = Auth::id();

// get all blocked users by auth user 
// note: you need to create BlockedUser model for blocked_user table  
$blocked_users=BlockedUser::where('user_id',$user_id)->pluck('blocked_id');

// get all posts without posts that created by blocked users
Post::whereNotIn('user_id',$blocked_users)->get();
```